# <div> element that has overflow-y set to "scroll" is shifting when dynamically adding elements to it in Microsoft Edge

Tags: firefox, microsoft-edge

This one should make many scratch their head...

Could someone let me know why my `<div>` element (id 'container') is shifting down when the overflow-y is set to "scroll" in Microsoft Edge?  Seems to work just fine in Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style>
        body {
            border: 3px dotted red; 
            position: fixed;

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            display: grid;
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center;

            overflow: hidden;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 95%; border: 2px dotted orange; background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="container" style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 60vmin; height: 95%; background-color: silver;"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            $('#container').append('<div style="border: 1px solid silver;">Hello World!</div>');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the screenshots for both Firefox and Microsoft Edge:

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Edge:
[image: Microsoft Edge]

Comment: Can you add screenshots from each browser?

Comment: I just added the screenshots.  See above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as below([demo](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/MWYPdMr)):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        border: 3px dotted red;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }   
</style>

<div style="height: 95%; width: 60vmin; border: 2px dotted orange; background-color: blue; overflow: hidden; margin-right:20px ; margin-top:20px; float:right">
    <div id="container" style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 60vmin; height: 100%; background-color: silver;"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            $('#container').append('<div style="border: 1px solid silver;">Hello World!</div>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The result in Microsoft Edge browser as below:

[image]

Comment: Very funny that "float:right"..., but I understand why! LOL

Comment: So it looks like the problem is he "display: grid" style against the body tag.  What's up with that?  Why does it work for Mozilla Firefox and not Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the issue is related to the `display:grid`, It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. As a temporary workaround, you could try to use the above code, if I get any solution or feedback about the `display:grid`, I will try to provide you in the future. Thanks for your understanding.